# Lack of moderator patience and deleting critical comments

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

A moderator closed [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15879/can-the-growing-trend-towards-globalisation-be-reversed?noredirect=1#comment57320_15879) in a very short space of time by using their moderator privilege.  The question was given no time for community self-organization or improvement.

The question was then modified and I and another poster discussed the moderator response to the question in the comments.

The moderator has returned to the question and refused to re-open it despite the edits however **they have deleted the comments** and other innocuous comments about globalisation questions in general.

I have used the Flag for Moderator attention Flag which was declined with the following statement

> Please only use this flag for items which require actual moderator attention

However, this is completely at odds with this statement from the SE Meta which states

[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges)

> Use the Flag for Moderator so that a Diamond Moderator can become involved.  Since that is the only recourse to Moderator issues other than the Contact Us link on the page.

This is frankly unnacceptable behaviour and the moderator has requested that criticism be articulated in the Meta, so here we are.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54318/discussion-on-question-by-venture2099-lack-of-moderator-patience-and-deleting-cr).

Comment: By the way, I declined your flag, because My best interpretation was that it was a request to reopen, and I decided that the question was too broad to reopen.  We also have a voting queue for reopening questions, and no moderator intervention is required

Comment: Fair enough. :thumbup:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to add to the sentiment that legitimate questions are routinely being shut down too quickly on marginal grounds.

The "opinion-based" ground, in particular, is being used far too loosely.

In some sense every interesting question about politics has an opinion component. But, that doesn't mean that someone can't have an intelligent, well researched or supported answer that explains the opinions that people have on particular issues without the answer itself being opinion based.

For instance, a recent question asked why the [Labour Party of the U.K. was declining](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16098/why-is-the-labour-party-in-such-significant-decline) in the polls and in public support. There are plenty a entirely legitimate ways that question could be answered that would shed light on this legitimate question about politics that are more than the personal opinion of the person writing the answer. Indeed, these are just the sort of questions that professional political scientists and political commentators answer every day.

The possibility that someone might provide a glib or unconsidered answer is a problem with the person writing the answer, not the question itself. The causes of globalization can be answers appropriately, and if the answers are bad, downgrade the answers not the question.

Answer (score 12):

It is important to close questions quickly, because otherwise they attract the kind of answers we don't want to have on this website.

Why it was the right decision to to close this question quickly can be seen in [the duplicate of the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15892/can-the-growing-trend-towards-economic-globalisation-be-reversed) the author created a while later. It quickly received two answers which were merely short, personal opinions not backed by any sources or research. I can hardly imagine that this is the kind of answer any reader of Politics.SE expects to such a complex issue as globalization.

We expect people to post answers which are more than just a short summary of what they *feel* is right. We expect people to actually do research and show that research to prove they didn't just made it up. We also don't want answers which are just opinions. We want answers which look at the issue from a neutral point of view and provide the information one needs to form an own opinion. We also don't want partial answers which only address one aspect of the question. We expect answers which look at the topic from all angles and provide an all-encompassing answer.

In order to provide that grade of quality, a question must be reasonably scoped. Globalization is a very complex issue. Whole libraries of books and research papers were written about that issue. And a proper answer to the question "can globalization be reversed" would be yet another book. [As the help center says](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

---

Regarding deleted comments: The purpose of comments is to provide feedback to a question or answer in form of asking for clarification or providing constructive criticism for the content of the post.

Some of the comments I deleted were mini-answers which attempted to answer the question. There is a reason why the Stackexchange software separates *comments* and *answers* to a question. If someone wants to answer a question, they should write a "real" answer which fulfills our above described quality criteria. When they don't feel like investing that much work, they shouldn't try to circumvent that by just writing it as a comment.

Others were [meta-comments](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) which addressed the question being closed. They were not addressing *why* it was closed, but just the fact that it was closed at all. This belong on meta and not on the question itself.

---

Regarding the personal critique why I didn't reply to this meta-question earlier: The author was clearly angry at me, and I was angry at him. As you can see from [the chat discussion between him and yannis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54318/discussion-on-question-by-venture2099-lack-of-moderator-patience-and-deleting-cr), you can see that civilized discourse wasn't really possible at that moment:

> Venture2099: Not happy with Phillip acting like a little bitch
>
> yannis: Stop acting like a buffoon please.

When people end up in petty name-calling, you are on an emotional level where conflict resolution is impossible. So I decided to sleep a night about the issue to give both me and the author a while to calm down and address the issue in a civilized manner.

Comment: The above closing approach overvalues the quality of modern statistical research, (which is sometimes just tailored partisan bean counting), and undervalues logical and analytical answers, (which, if sound, helps to separate the wheat from the chaff).